# Import CSV file into SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert varchar column to datetime](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17904/convert-varchar-column-to-datetime)

Hi I am using the SQL server Import wizard to import a CSV file into what will be a new table in my database.

An example of the CSV file is:

```
66.29.193.125 ,-,  -,  07/May/2012:00:00:00, 0 , "GET / " , 200, 123, "-", "-"
```

Everything imports ok when the default varchar type is used for all columns. However, the 4th entry in is clearly a datetime and I want to import it as a datetime. anytime I try, I get:

```
Error 0xc02020a1: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "Column 3" returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

I get these for the various datetime types. Any tips? 
Many thanks.